# How to switch REACT NATIVE js file to Android Activity

Tags: android, facebook, reactjs, npm, react-native

I need to switch from **REACT NATIVE Activity** to **native android activity** on button click event from JS file. I already have searched a lot. Please help me.

Comment: I have tried much to solve it out, the 2 answers are also unable to solve the problem. It should have not been on hold.

Answer (score 2):

Create an intent filter for your Native android activity

```
<activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Use [Linking openURL](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#openurl) api.

```
Linking.openURL('my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here')
```

[Link to sample application working](https://github.com/agenthunt/react-native-scratchpad/tree/master/LaunchNativeActivity)

Comment: getting error :

console.error: "An error occurred", {"framesToPop":1,"code":"EUNSPECIFIED"}, stack:
                                                                    error@56404:12
                                                                    <unknown>@15859:94

Comment: line below was missing:
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>

Answer (score 2):

You can create a module and expose a `ReactMethod` to JS which will open the activity for you.

```
public class RctActivityModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RctActivity";

    public RctActivityModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @ReactMethod @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void startActivity(String extraParam) {
        Activity context = ContextProvider.getActivityContext();
        if (context != null && !context.isFinishing()) {
            Intent rctActivityIntent = new Intent(context, RctActivity.class);
            rctActivityIntent.putExtra(RctActivity.EXTRA_PARAM, extraParam);
            context.startActivity(rctActivityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add your new module to your package

```
public class RCCPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(
                new RctActivityModule(reactContext)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Create a JS file representing your module (`RctActivity.js`). For now place it in the root directory of your react-native project.

RctActivity.js :

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
module.exports = NativeModules.RctActivity;
```

In your JavaScript code (index.js), import the `RctActivity` module:

`import RctActivity from './RctActivity'`

and use the method you've exposed like this:
`RctActivity.startActivity('MyExtraParam');`

**Edit:**
In order to open a new activity, I had to keep a reference to the current running activity. So I've used this little helper class:

```
public class ContextProvider {
    private static WeakReference<Activity> sActivityWR;

    public static void setActivityContext(Activity activity) {
        if (sActivityWR == null) {
            sActivityWR = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
    }

    public static Activity getActivityContext() {
        return sActivityWR != null ? sActivityWR.get() : null;
    }

    public static void clearActivityContext() {
        if (sActivityWR != null) {
            sActivityWR.clear();
        }
        sActivityWR = null;
    }
}
```

To use it, wire it to your base activities `onResume` and `onPause` methods:

```
public class RctActivity extends com.facebook.react.ReactActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.v(getTag(), "onResume");
        ContextProvider.setActivityContext(this);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.v(getTag(), "onPause");
        ContextProvider.clearActivityContext();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Don't forget that now your `MainActivity` needs to extend `RctActivity`

Comment: can not resolve "ContextProvider" in class "RctActivityModule".

Comment: Context provider is a little helper class i've wrote. I'll add it to the answer

Comment: I am importing in js file:
import './home/ttnd/ReactTestProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/reacttestproject/RctActivity' .....and facing error.........


Requiring unknown module "./home/ttnd/ReactTestProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/reacttestproject/RctActivity". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager

Comment: It's common practice to create a JavaScript representation of your native module.

Create a js file and name it `RctActivity`. 
`import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';`
`module.exports = NativeModules.RctActivity;`

Comment: I have restarted the application but again facing error, Requiring unknown module

Comment: Here is my index.android.js: see the url:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Jjwu6YBv43d0sYLGEA0KfLoY-hFKQRBcz9c1FXSm9Ds/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've updated my answer. Are you sure you've added `RctActivityModule` to your package ? In your base activity (MainActivity) which extends `ReactActivity` you need to override `getPackages()` and return a list which contains your package. Did you do that ?

Comment: @Shivang in your index file, you've imported RctActivity.java. You need to import the JS representation of your Java class. I've updated my answer.